# Is it possible to paste more than one line into GitHub?

Tags: github, newline, copy-paste, paste

When **pasting code** into a repo via GitHub's web-app, all the lines get squashed into a single line, like this:

`line1line2line3line4line5`

Is there a way to paste multiple lines into GitHub's online editor?

What I've tried:

- I tried adding an extra  after each line, but it did not help.  All the 's and 's still got ignored.
- I even tried *momentarily* installing Adobe Flash because [this article](https://techcrunch.com/2013/01/02/github-replaces-copy-and-paste-with-zeroclipboard/) states that Github is/was using ZeroClipboard.  Flash did not help.

Comment: Not normal behavior. Contact https://github.com/contact and give details on what browser, editor, sample file of text illustrating the issue, etc.